# How to determine Type of value types

Tags: c#

How do you find the `Type` of a value type in C#?

Let's say i have:

```
string str;
int value;
double doubleValue;
```

Is there a method that returns the Type of any of these value types?

To be clearer, I am trying something like this:

```
string str = "Hello";
string typeOfValue = <call to method that returns the type of the variable `str`>

if (typeOfValue == "string") {
    //do something
 } else {
   //raise exception
 }
```

I want to get input from the user and raise an exception if the value entered is not a `string` or `int` or `double` depending on my conditions.

I have tried:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num;
        string value;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value");

        value  = Console.ReadLine();
        bool isNum = Int32.TryParse(value, out num);

        if (isNum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Correct value entered.");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong value entered.");

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

but what if the type of value I want to check is a `string` or something else?

Comment: `Object.GetType`?! But it's not clear, the user can enter only strings. So the type is always string. If you parse it to a number type you know already the type at compile time.

Comment: Just a side note, `string` is not a value type

Comment: I'm not seeing *why* you need this here. This could be useful if you had an `Object`, but a string read from the console is a string and nothing else unless you parse it, then the parse result is a known type at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on any element in .Net since it exists at the object level :

```
var myStringType = "string".GetType();
myStringType == typeof(string) // true
```

GetType returns a `Type` object, you can get a readable human friendly name by using the `Name` property on the `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

`GetType` will return the correct result:

```
string typeOfValue = value.GetType().ToString();
```

But in this instance, you do not need to convert the type to a string for the comparison:

```
if (typeof(String) == value.GetType()) ...
```